# How to make a spinner from string?

Tags: android, string, file, spinner, sharedpreferences

I have this problem. I read with BufferedReader text from one system file, this text contains for example 5 WORDS, but in another case it can contain less or more words, then I put this text (these words) to ONE string and save that string to shared preferences.

**And my question is that how can I make a spinner from this string?**

**I have seen it's possible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your preferences string looks like, but assuming that the words are separated with a ",".

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, yourString.split(","));
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: It works, but it gives me all words to the one row in spinner, but I need to make a options from that words. For example: if that file includes 5 words, I need to have those 5 words as 5 options in spinner.

Comment: Words are separated only by spaces. In that file.

Comment: yourString.split(" ") ... This should split the String you get from the file into your 5 words. Basically, you want to get your 5 words into some type of Array or ArrayList and pass that as the last argument to the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Yes, I know, I had tried it, but it didn't work for the first time because when I read string from file I used text.append("\n"); and with this line it didn't work, but when I deleted this line it works. Thank you. I have a one question yet, could you help me please? I want to if user select one this option from string (one word) I need to put this word to other file. I will use echo command for ii, it is not problem, but I don't know how to know which word user sellect. In normal spinner there is for example if(possition==0), etc. but I can't use in this case I think.

Comment: Post it as a new question! StackOverflow doesn't allow question/answer in comments.